# Running an rsync command from a variable -- quoting not honored

Tags: linux, bash, rsync, quotations

I know there are guides and answers regarding quotes. I have read them (all day long), but i still cannot get my simple script to work.

I have set up script1.sh and try to run a command. The command has to be read to a variable so I can echo it, run it and do other stuff with it maybe later.

my command is

```
rsync -vtirn -e ssh --exclude '._*' --exclude '.@*' --exclude '.DS_Store' --progress /Path/ user@IP:/Path
```

it works as expected if i run it from bash and if i put it in my script.

If I put a variable in between, the --excludes are not working anymore.

```
job='rsync -vtirn -e ssh --exclude '"'"'._*'"'"' --exclude '"'"'.@*'"'"' --exclude '"'"'.DS_Store'"'"' --progress /Path/ user@IP:/Path
echo $job   
$job
```

The strange thing is, that the echo shows exactly the command i need. If i copy the echo output and paste it into the shell, the command is working correct. But the command started with $job is ommiting the excludes.

I have been trying with double quotes at the beginning and end, with escaping single quotes (/'), with only double quotes... so many different options, but nothing considered my --exclude 'filter' argument. The only thing that worked is

```
job=$(rsync -vtirn -e ssh --exclude '._*' --exclude '.@*' --exclude '.DS_Store' --progress /Path/ user@IP:/Path)
```

but with this the command is started as soon as the variable is set.

thanks in advance for any help

Comment: This is discussed in detail in [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use regular variables to store command names. Define a function.

```
job () {
  rsync -vtirn -e ssh --exclude '._*' --exclude '.@*' --exclude '.DS_Store' --progress /Path/ user@IP:/Path
}
```

If you really need a single form for logging and execution, define an array to store the arguments to `rsync`.

```
opts=( -vtrin 
       -e ssh
       --exclude '._*'
       --exclude '.@*'
       --exclude .DS_Store
       --progress
       /Path/
       user@IP:/Path
)
echo "rsync ${opts[*]}"
rsync "${opts[@]}"
```

The log won't be *exactly* the same as the command you execute, but it doesn't need to be; you aren't passing the log message to `eval`.

Comment: I'd consider `printf '%q '  "${opts[@]}"; echo` to provide logging that could be copied-and-pasted with the same effect as actually running the command; as it is, `echo`'s output can be misleading.

Comment: thank you for your (working) example, I will try to take it from here. I tried to figure out what the differences are between   `echo "rsync ${opts[*]}"`, `echo "rsync ${opts[@]}"` and `printf '%q ' "${opts[@]}"; echo`. I added all three of them to my script an the all print the same (except the rsync for the last one)